# chainStyle with if condition in databinding

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding, android-jetpack

I have a problem in making the chainStyle depend on condition come from data , so if the data is null I need the chain style to be spread , otherwise it will be packed

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_data"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/relativeLayout"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="@{gameState.data== null ? spread :  packed }" />
```

Could not find identifier 'spread'

Check that the identifier is spelled correctly, and that no  or  tags are missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must add identifier's using it's class. like when you want add visibility using condition.

so you must import `ConstraintLayout` to your xml in data the use it.
some thing like this.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="model"
            type="...." />

        <import type="androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="@{gameState.data== null ? LayoutParams.CHAIN_SPREAD :  LayoutParams.CHAIN_PACKED}"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```